# WhatsApp e-mail conversation with Java

Tags: java, php, android, email

I'm a starter in Android Programming, and I need some API/algorithm by which I can invoke the "email conversation" in WhatsApp without opening WhatsApp itself.

Searched WhatsApp FAQ, they give `whatsapp://send?text=` as the code to send text messages without actually opening the app.

Is there some way to do the same task for email conversation?

Comment: "Seached WhatsApp FAQ, they give whatsapp://send?text= as the code to send text messages without actually opening the app" -- no, that will open the app. Quoting [the FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012) that you (presumably) read: "Opening whatsapp://send?text= followed by the text to send, **will open WhatsApp**, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input field with the specified text." (emphasis added).

Comment: Yes, it will open the app. But it gives some "privilege" to enter the text message before actually opening the app. On the same lines, is there a way in which I can invoke the email conversation command, which may or may not open WhatsApp for selecting the contact.